# TP4056 with load sharing

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

Does the TP406 with protection also needs a load sharing circuit?
I got the following schematic. But I saw [this](https://blog.zakkemble.net/a-lithium-battery-charger-with-load-sharing/) post on load sharing. Can I add that to this design too? I could not really find a good schematic for that.

[image]

The design than would look a bit like this:

[image]

The goal of the design is to power a MCU via the USB, and if needed charge the lipo too, when full, only use the USB power.

### update

Should this work?
[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of D4? I've never seen a TP4056 circuit use one before. But yes, something like this should do the job.

Comment: I placed D4 to prefent current from flowing to the TP4056

Comment: Not needed. And you have Q4 the wrong way round. How will power reach Vcc when the USB is connected?

Comment: @Finbarr thanks for pointing that out! What do you mean with "how will power reach Vcc"?

Comment: Q4 is there to switch battery power to Vcc when no power is supplied to the USB port, correct? How does power reach Vcc when the battery is being charged and Q4 is off?

Comment: Ahh I see, I just used that link from above. Do you have a idea how i need to edit the design?

Comment: Take another look at that article you linked, it shows a Schottky diode supplying power to Vcc when charging.

Comment: Ahh now I see, thanks you men!

Comment: Could you check the new design I made?